# Instagram API on Umbraco CMS

Tags: html, api, umbraco, instagram

I have a problem, can u help me to solve it?

I need to run an API to import all the latest pics from Instagram to a website built in Umbraco platform.

I wanna do something like this: [phpInstagramAPI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-instagram1/), but I can't use PHP with Umbraco..

Comment: To query data from Instagram you need to pass access token with the endpoint you are requesting, So, you can do the same with asp.net we well

Comment: Can you show me some example? I'm still half-minded about it.

Comment: Do you know how to make HTTP request in asp.net?

Comment: No. I just know it in php or using ajax (jQuery)..

Comment: Try this [InstaSharp](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Skybrud.Social to help facilitate the calling the Instagram APIs from your backend code. It is well documented at: http://social.skybrud.dk/instagram/. There is a [package](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/skybrudsocial-for-umbraco-7/) for using it with Umbraco but as the package description mentions, "Even though Skybrud.Social for Umbraco 7 is a package made for Umbraco, there is a good chance that you only need Skybrud.Social."

If you just want to display recent Instagram photos on your site, it might be easier to go with a client-side solution like [LightWidget](https://lightwidget.com/).